# When to call grecaptcha.execute() when using Invisible Captcha V2

Tags: javascript, ajax, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

So I added invisible recaptcha successfully but I'm curious what others think if I did it the correct way when calling grecaptcha.execute()

I call grecaptcha.execute() right after doing an explicit call like so

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback473&render=explicit"
    async defer>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var onloadCallback473 = function() {


     widgetId_473 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_473', {
      'sitekey' : 'MY KEY XXXXXXXXXXX',
                            'size' : 'invisible',
                'badge' : 'inline',                         });

            grecaptcha.execute(widgetId_473);

            };



    </script>
```

The form sits below this because of ASYNC DEFER

Now when a user submits the form by AJAX, I have code that handles it like this

```
'success': function(response) {

        if (response.success) {


        }
        else { 

         //validation error
         //Like blank fields, incorrect email requirements... etc 


        grecaptcha.reset(widgetId_473);
        grecaptcha.execute(widgetId_473);


        }
```

**My question is "Is it okay to call the function grecaptcha.execute() twice?"**

Like before hitting the submit button and after in the error section?

Comment: Why not call `.execute()` once only when the form validation is done?

Answer (score 2):

In broad terms, I call .execute() as soon as the form is submitted and send the ReCAPTCHA string key alongside the form data so the backend can effectively call google API and verify the ReCAPTCHA key before proceeding with any further logic.